# On change pass the value of select option box in url

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to pass the value of option box in url on onchange event.I have to pass the value of selected option box to some.php file.Here i am tried out but it's not working for me.

**Bellow is my sample code**

```
<select id="font" onchange="document.getElementById('font').src='some.php?fontname='+this.value">
       <option value="arial"  >arial</option>
       <option value="stencil" >stencil</option>
       </select>
```

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: `select` does not have an `src` property, what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: i have converted text to image after converting image i have option to change the font that text  to pass the input text value i am using below code <img class="stencil-mains" id="stencil-mains" />    
        <span class="line" style="margin-left: 578px;">Line 2 Text-</span><input type="text" name="stencil-text" style="margin-left: 15px;"
       onkeyup="document.getElementById('stencil-mains').src='some.php?img='+this.value" />  its working good now i just want change the font of existing text which is appearing check out the demo http://stencils.bluecoresyspvtltd.com/stackdemo/

Answer (score 0):

You need to use javascript `location.href` for redirecting.

```
<select id="font" onchange="window.location.href='some.php?fontname='+this.value">
<option value="arial"  >arial</option>
<option value="stencil" >stencil</option>
</select>
```

Comment: i don't want redirect on page i just have to pass the value and get it on some .php